# How can I keep Dataverse and Postgres in sync?

Tags: powerapps, dataverse, powerapps-modeldriven

I'm currently tasked into integrating an existing Postgres database with a PowerApp that uses Dataverse. The Postgres database already has a server depending on it and some coded apps. I've seen the limitations of using connectors, and I see that our PowerApp features depend on what Dataverse offers.

How can I keep the Postgres database in sync with Dataverse and vice-versa? Are there any 3rd party tools too?

I tried doing it manually through a REST API, but it will clutter the code, and might end up with different sets of data between databases if one of the requests fail.